Cashew nut data set
I am looking for a dataset on cashews that contains a healthy trunk of cashews.
You can also let me know if there are other cashew nut related data sets.For example, the real fruit of cashews, leaves, trunks, and relevant planting information (soil temperature and humidity, etc.)
